# Combine two python list using its value logic - Python

Tags: python, list

I would like to combine two lists in Python to make one list in the following way:

```
a = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]

b= ["Sun", "is", "bright", "June","and" ,"July", "Sara", "goes", "to", "school"]
```

and the output:

```
c= ["Sun is bright", "June and July", "Sara goes to school"]
```

Comment: "the following way" - What way?

Answer (score 4):

Use a `for` loop to first accumulate the words into some kind of mapping data structure, and then use a list comprehension to create the desired output.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in zip(a, b):
...     d[k].append(v)
...     
>>> [' '.join(d[k]) for k in sorted(d)]
['Sun is bright', 'June and July', 'Sara goes to school']
```

Comment: I think you can get rid of the O(n log n) sorting with an `OrderedDict` and by using `d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)` instead of relying on a defaultdict.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that:

a and b have the same length

a is ordered

a begin with 1

Try:

```
a = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]

b= ["Sun", "is", "bright", "June","and" ,"July", "Sara", "goes", "to", "school"]

c = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    if len(c)<a[i]:
       c.append(b[i])
    else:
       c[a[i]-1] += " " + b[i]

print c
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you.  You can create a list of lists and always append to the last inner_list.  Then, combine all the lists into a string using `join`.

```
a = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
b= ["Sun", "is", "bright", "June","and" ,"July", "Sara", "goes", "to", "school"]
final_list = []
for i,word in zip(a,b):
    if i-1 >= len(final_list):
        final_list.append([])
    final_list[-1].append(word)

combined = [" ".join(inner_list) for inner_list in final_list]
#['Sun is bright', 'June and July', 'Sara goes to school']
```

Answer (score 1):

Another idea, using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(a) # Counter({3: 4, 1: 3, 2: 3})
i = 0
res = []
for j in sorted(c):
    res.append(' '.join(b[i:c[j]+i]))
    i += c[j]

print(res) # ['Sun is bright', 'June and July', 'Sara goes to school']
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming len(a) == len(b) and a straight forward way, not be the best solution in terms time complexity and code length. Toddler at Stackoverflow, trying to contribute.

```
result = []

def solution():
    ctr = 0
    a = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5 ]
    b= ["Sun", "is", "bright", "June","and" ,"July", "Sara", "goes", "to", "school", "Ravi","Stackoverflow","Solution"]

    length = len(a)
    i = 0
    temp = ""

    while(i < length ):

        if i == 0:
            temp = b[i]
        else:
            if i == length -1 and a[i] != a[i-1]:
                result.append(temp)
                result.append(b[i]) 
            elif a[i] == a[i-1] and i != length - 1:
                temp = temp+" "+b[i]
            elif i == length - 1:
                temp = temp+" "+b[i]
                result.append(temp)
                temp = b[i]
            else:
                result.append(temp)
                temp = b[i]

        i = i + 1
    return result

print solution()
```

Output: ['Sun is bright', 'June and July', 'Sara goes to school', 'Ravi Stackoverflow', 'Solution']

Answer (score 0):

Assuming words in a group (numbers in `a`) are always adjacent,

```
from itertools import groupby

def group_words(words, index):
    index = iter(index)
    return [' '.join(ws) for _, ws in groupby(words, key=lambda _: next(index))]
```

And you can pass your lists,

```
>>> group_words(b, a)
['Sun is bright', 'June and July', 'Sara goes to school']
```

If you want a one-liner that is a bit harder to read you can also do,

```
>>> [' '.join([w for _, w in it]) for _, it in groupby(zip(a, b), key=lambda t: t[0])]
['Sun is bright', 'June and July', 'Sara goes to school']
```